# Getting the number of people in circles on Google Plus

Tags: php, wordpress, json

I'm trying to get the number of people in circles on Google Plus with:

```
$gplus_data = wp_remote_get('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/'.$googleplus_user.'?key='.$api_key);
$gplus_data = json_decode($gplus_data['body'],true);
$gplus_count = $gplus_data['circledByCount'];
```

but I'm gettting an error in the last line.

The `json` object looks like:

```
{
 "kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "\"pSkIL41GT2wmAdFX5kPW-Rf7v4A/dRTsk1U7uBI-ekf4-a2fEZl8eGs\"",
 "urls": [
  {
   "value": "",
   "label": ""
  }
 ],
 "objectType": "page",
 "id": "",
 "displayName": "",
 "tagline": "",
 "aboutMe": "",
 "url": "",
 "image": {
  "url": ""
 },
 "isPlusUser": true,
 "plusOneCount": 22556,
 "circledByCount": 1398,
 "verified": false,
 "cover": {
  "layout": "banner",
  "coverPhoto": {
   "url": "",
   "height": 528,
   "width": 940
  },
  "coverInfo": {
   "topImageOffset": -126,
   "leftImageOffset": 0
  }
 }
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `circledByCount` value is not being returned by the API for normal user profiles, only to G+ Pages. Not even on the [developers page *Try it* section](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get).

According to this [release note](https://developers.google.com/+/release-notes/?hl=en), my emphasis:

> Nov 2012 release
>
> Added the following properties to the people resource
>
> - [...]
> - plusOneCount (only for Google+ Pages)
> - circledByCount (**only for Google+ Pages**)

Your last line should be:

```
$gplus_count = isset( $gplus_data['circledByCount'] ) ? $gplus_data['circledByCount'] : '';
```

I tested with this code:

```
$g_user = USER_ID;
$api_key = API_KEY;

$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/'.$g_user.'?key='.$api_key;
$response = wp_remote_get( $url );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) )
{
    
    $body = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
    var_dump( $body );
}
elseif( isset($response['body']['error'] ) ) 
{
    var_dump( $response['body']['error'] );
}
```

Comment: perfect work with `file_get_contents()` but with `wp_remote_get` return `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in`